# How to compare a nested list of Dicts to another nested list of Dicts and update the values in one from the other

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have 2 lists of dicts, both with further nesting in them, the first list of dicts called `original_state` below is (as it suggests) the initial state received when the server is switched on.

A script executes (which is how the initial state is obtained) and continues to look for updates. These updates come through periodically in the form of `updated_orders` below (this all functions correctly).

I am trying (and failing miserably) to try and write a function that looks at the list of dicts `updated_orders` and then adds those orders into the correct place within `original_state`. The correct place is determined by the 'selection_id' and the 'market_id'.

Things to consider:

1) There could be selection_id's in `updated_orders` that do not exist in `original_state` (the reverse will be true most of the time as orders are only returned when they come in, hence most selection_id's in `original_state` will not have a corresponding value in `updated_orders`, but this is less important as `updated_orders` does not need to be updated).

2) When a selection_id is in `updated_orders` and not in `original_state` a new entry should be added, when a selection_id is in both then any new order_id's should be inserted and any existing ones overwritten if different.

3) The above also applies for Market_id's (which adds a whole new level of complexity, so please feel free to ignore this for now as this is a relatively unlikely scenario that I can deal with down the line and/or by another method).

3) An order_id is totally unique

4) A market_id is totally unique

5) A selection_id could occur in more than one market

6) If it helps, market_id is an available field to use within `live_orders` next to 'selection_id' (it is omitted in the example data set I've given)

I think that's all the logic, hopefully I've explained it clearly, but please feel free to ask for clarification on anything.

Now the embarrassing bit...I would normally post an extensive code snippet for people to critique, however here I really don't even know where to begin, so although I have tried plenty of ways my syntax has never been valid, hence I have made virtually no progress.

I obviously don't expect anyone to write everything for me, so if someone is kind enough to give me a pointer I can then hopefully complete the function and post the final code to help anyone else with a similar issue.

```
original_state = [{'Market_id': '1.130856098', 'Market_name': 'Market A', 'position_list':  
[{'Market_id': '1.130856098', 'Selection_id': 12832765, 'Last_price': 4.1,  
 'Orders':
[{'order_id': '163785114305', 'price': 100, 'size': 5.0},  
{'order_id': '173785114311', 'price': 99, 'size': 5.0}], 'Status': 'ACTIVE'},
{'Market_id': '1.130856099', 'Selection_id': 12832767, 'Last_price': 4.1,  
 'Orders':
[{'order_id': '163785114305', 'price': 100, 'size': 5.0}, 
 {'order_id': '173785114311', 'price': 99, 'size': 5.0}], 'Status': 'ACTIVE'}]},
{'Market_id': '1.130856099', 'Market_name': 'Market B', 'position_list':
[{'Market_id': '1.130856099', 'Selection_id': 12832765, 'Last_price': 4.1,  
 'Orders':
[{'order_id': '163785114305', 'price': 100, 'size': 5.0},  
{'order_id': '173785114311', 'price': 99, 'size': 5.0}], 'Status': 'ACTIVE'},
 {'Market_id': '1.130856099', 'Selection_id': 12832763, 'Last_price': 4.1,  
 'Orders':
[{'order_id': '163785114305', 'price': 100, 'size': 5.0},  
{'order_id': '173785114311', 'price': 99, 'size': 5.0}],  
'Status': 'ACTIVE'}]}]
```

```
updated_orders=[{'Last_update': 'Mon May 20 18:23:38 2019', 'Market_id': '1.130856098', 'Market_name': 'Market A',
'Live_orders':  
[{'selection_id': 12832765, 'live_orders':  
[{'order_id': '165150568348', 'price': 55.5, 'size': 3},
{'order_id': '165147033010', 'price': 46, 'size': 12}]},
{'selection_id': 12832767, 'live_orders':  
[{'order_id': '165150568333', 'price': 32, 'size': 3.5},
 {'order_id': '165147033055', 'price': 67, 'size': 7.8}]}]},
{'Last_update': 'Mon May 20 18:23:38 2019', 'Market_id': '1.130856099', 'Market_name': 'Market B',  
'Live_orders':  
[{'selection_id': 12832765, 'live_orders':  
[{'order_id': '165150568348', 'price': 55.5, 'size': 54},
{'order_id': '165147033010', 'price': 46, 'size': 9}]},  
{'selection_id': 12832766, 'live_orders':  
[{'order_id': '165150568349', 'price': 56, 'size': 6}, 
 {'order_id': '165147033011', 'price': 47, 'size': 32}]}]}]}]
```

```
new_order_list = []

for x in updated_orders:
    for y in x['Live_orders']:
        orders_to_update = {}
        orders_to_update.update({'Market_id': x['Market_id'],
                                'Selection_id': y['selection_id'],
                                'live_orders': y['live_orders']})
        new_order_list.append(orders_to_update)

for z in new_order_list:
    for a in original_state:
        for b in a['position_list']:
                if z['Market_id'] == b['Market_id'] and z['Selection_id'] == b['Selection_id']:
                    print(z['Market_id'], z['Selection_id'])
```

I wonder if I've been massively over complicating this, the above appears to filter in the way (I think) I require, so then the next step would be to update the `original_state` with `updated_orders` based on the above selections.

Comment: Sorry to whoever kindly re-formatted the dataset for me, I noticed an error as I was trying to do the same and appear to have over-written your effort.

Comment: And to those down voting based on the formatting...give me a minute or two, I'm trying to correct it!

Comment: Hopefully that should look a lot more readable now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have been massively over complicating things here, this appears to do what I want (ignoring the insertion of completely new markets / selection_id's for now):

```
new_order_list = []

for x in updated_orders:
    for y in x['Live_orders']:
        orders_to_update = {}
        orders_to_update.update({'Market_id': x['Market_id'],
                                'Selection_id': y['selection_id'],
                                'live_orders': y['live_orders']})
        new_order_list.append(orders_to_update)

for z in new_order_list:
    for a in original_state:
        for b in a['position_list']:
                if z['Market_id'] == b['Market_id'] and z['Selection_id'] == b['Selection_id']:
                    #for c in b['Orders']:
                    print(b['Market_id'], b['Selection_id'], z['live_orders'])
                    b.update({'Orders': z['live_orders']})
```

I must have missed the obvious solution and was looking for something far too complex, but hopefully this will help someone else as this must be a fairly common problem (yet with very few posts on the solution)!

Here is how I tackled the updates where the orders were not in the `original_state`:

```
uo_list = []

for i in updated_orders:
    uo_list.append(i['Market_id'])

os_list = []

for j in original_state:
    os_list.append(j['Market_id'])

new_list = list(set(uo_list).difference(os_list))

for i in updated_orders:
    for j in new_list:
        if i['Market_id'] == j:
            print('Append this as required', i)
```